# Cordova app crashed when local notification tried to occurs and app shows "open app again"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic 6, angular 10 and node 12. I am using cordova to deploy app and test local notification. I am trying to show local notification on click event but app crashed and show "charity app has stopped, open app again".

[image]

I tried fix it by removing the node_module, platform, plugins folder, config.xml file and install npm again and deploy app again but it still showing again. In my config file I am using `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="^5.28.0" />`. In package.json file dependency is `"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.28.0",` and devDepency is `"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",` and plugin is `"cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}`

I add also it in the app.module.ts file by using `import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';` this import. and in providers `LocalNotifications,`.

in notification.page.ts I import it by `import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';` and constructor injection `private localNotifications: LocalNotifications`.

Here Is code where I am showing local notification:

```
manageNotification() {
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      title: 'title of notification',
      text: 'details of notification goes here.'
    });
  }
```

Please help me How can I resolve it. If you require missing details please ask in comment.